# Library not loaded libpng16.16.dylib Because of incompatible version

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2, libpng

I'm trying to display an image on the screen, so I installed SDL2 image. I can successfully compile my code, but when I try to run the resulting executable it gives me this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/sdl2_image/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib requires version 54.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 51.0.0
```

I have tried running `brew upgrade libpng` and `brew update`, but neither worked. I'm not sure what I can do to fix this.

In case it helps, here's the code I used.

In main.cpp:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

#undef main

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Getting Started", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Event input;
    bool quit = false;

    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* temp = IMG_Load("some_image.png");

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, temp);

    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = 500;
    rect.w = 100;
    rect.h = 100;

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&input) > 0) {
            if (input.type == SDL_QUIT) quit = true;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

And in Makefile:

```
main:
    g++ main.cpp -o image -I include -L lib -l SDL2-2.0.0 -l SDL2_image-2.0.0
```

Comment: You might need to download, build, and install libpng directly -- brew might not have a sufficiently-recent copy.

Comment: Just use jpg image - it was the simplest solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by deleting the libpng folder in `/usr/local/Cellar` and installing it with `brew install libpng` all over again.